# Why postgresql does not use index in this query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Here is the complete table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE search.tablename
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(300) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tablename_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX tablename_name_idx
  ON search.tablename
  USING btree
  (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

It has ~73k rows and was just vacuumed/analyzed by manual run.

What I cannot understand is why this trivial query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM "tablename" AS "arn" 
 WHERE arn.name LIKE 'foo%'
```

does not use the corresponding index.

The execution plan for this query is

```
Seq Scan on tablename arn  (cost=0.00..1626.96 rows=7 width=47) (actual time=8.682..8.682 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: ((name)::text ~~ 'foo%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 73197
Total runtime: 8.703 ms
```

Could anyone point to what I am missing?

**UPD**: changing column name type to `text` changes nothing.

**UPD 2**: `name = 'foo'` predicate expectedly uses index

Comment: Interesting. Can you try EXPLAIN ANALYZE for SELECT * 
  FROM search.tablename
 WHERE name LIKE 'foo%'

Comment: @Jayadevan it's identical (it would surprise me even more if it wouldn't :-)

Comment: In one case you are specifying the schema name and in the other, you are not. I just wondered if the query was going against a different table altogether.

Comment: @Jayadevan I'm sure you will be curious to see the answer below :-)

Comment: zerkms Thanks. It is an eye-opener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding [varchar_pattern_ops](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html) to your index

```
CREATE INDEX tablename_name_idx
  ON search.tablename
  USING btree
  (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

> The operator classes text_pattern_ops, varchar_pattern_ops,
>   bpchar_pattern_ops, and name_pattern_ops support B-tree indexes on the
>   types text, varchar, char, and name, respectively. The difference from
>   the default operator classes is that the values are compared strictly
>   character by character rather than according to the locale-specific
>   collation rules. This makes these operator classes suitable for use by
>   queries involving pattern matching expressions (LIKE or POSIX regular
>   expressions) when the server does not use the standard "C" locale.

Comment: That's it. One of the chapters or postgresql manual that I skipped due to "I will never do such a weird things". Does it mean one must always use `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` `=` `C`? I've tried to make a research on them several times but failed to get a clear understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best practice is regarding using the C locale. Personally I use en_US.UTF-8 along with the _pattern_ops classes

Comment: @zerkms definitely don't change your locale for this - use _pattern_ops as FuzzyTree says

Comment: @JackDouglas that's what I have in my mind, **BUT** what confuses me pretty much is another answer from a person I respect really much here on DBA.SE: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46409/37113

Comment: @zerkms I was confusing database encoding with locale - and you are right, Erwin is great. Please read this entire thread and make up your own mind: http://postgresql.nabble.com/C-locale-versus-en-US-UTF8-Was-String-comparision-in-PostgreSQL-td5721780.html but basically it comes down to the question of what sorting you prefer to see by default.

Comment: @zerkms please see Erwin's reply to my comment on the question you linked to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46408/how-to-choose-a-collation-for-international-database/46409?noredirect=1#comment154286_46409 FuzzyTree sorry to spam you.