# Why isn't Postgres using my index?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my table (actually a materialized view), in Postgres 9.4:

```
  Materialized view "public.vw_presentation_summary"
      Column       |         Type          | Modifiers
-------------------+-----------------------+-----------
 processing_date   | date                  |
 presentation_code | character varying(15) |
 items             | numeric               |
 cost              | double precision      |
Indexes:
    "vw_idx_presentation_summary" btree (presentation_code)
```

I have just run `VACUUM ANALYZE vw_presentation_summary`, so the query planner should be up to date.

Now if I run `explain (analyse, buffers) select * from vw_presentation_summary where presentation_code LIKE '0205051I0BB%'` this is what I see:

```
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on vw_presentation_summary  (cost=0.00..23202.16 rows=182 width=32) (actual time=0.440..222.383 rows=224 loops=1)
   Filter: ((presentation_code)::text ~~ '0205051I0BB%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1115229
   Buffers: shared hit=9259
 Planning time: 0.760 ms
 Execution time: 222.524 ms
(6 rows)
```

Explain link: http://explain.depesz.com/s/nTL4

Why is this running a Seq Scan not an index lookup?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-opclass.html

Comment: Relevant (I would even say a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/27435980/251311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator can not be implemented with a regular index except when using the "C" locale, hence you get a sequential scan over all rows. What you need is a [varchar_pattern_ops index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html) on your column "presentation_code". So you should have an index like so:

```
CREATE INDEX "vw_idx_presentation_summary_vcops"
  ON "vw_presentation_summary" (presentation_code varchar_pattern_ops);
```

You could also consider a [trigram index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html), although that would not be strictly necessary here.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought that my database was using the C locale, but on checking it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

There are only two reasons for a database not to use an index:

1. It can't (index is not eligible)
2. It doesn't want to (optimizer estimates that full scan will be faster)

**Correction:** I initially thought that this was the case of #2, but as another answer has explained, it is in fact #1.

Comment: At an approximate 1.11 million rows in the table, your suggestion is impossible.

Comment: oops, my bad. I was looking at "rows=182", but that's the output size estimate. I missed the "Rows Removed by Filter: 1115229" part.